# Closing one "your bounty expires in the next 24 hours" banner closes them all

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, bounties, notification-bar

A moment ago, I had two "The bounty on your question expires in the next 24 hours" notification banners active here on MSO. I closed one, and it disappeared as expected. When I moved on to another question, both banners were gone.

I can see how this logic made sense back in the one-bounty-at-a-time days, but now that users can have three simultaneous open bounties each, the dismissal button should only dismiss the selected notification.

**EDIT :**
Although this is marked completed, it happened again today.

Answer (score 6):

Our code responsible for "message dismissal" used the message type as opposed to message id as the key for ridding the user of messages.

I just changed it so, in general, we dismiss on message id now. If we need any notifications to dismiss based on "family", let me know so I can special case it.

Keep in mind that many messages get dismissed by simply visiting the profile page.